# How to initialize a pool of python multiprocessing workers with a shared state?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, data-science, gensim

I am trying to execute in parallel [some machine learning algorithm](https://github.com/amirouche/wikimark/).

When I use multiprocessing, it's slower than without. My wild guess is that the `pickle` serialization of the models I use slowing down the whole process. So the question is: *how can I initialize the pool's worker with an initial state so that I don't need to serialize/deserialize for every single call the models?*

Here is my current code:

```
import pickle
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter
from multiprocessing import Pool

from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec

from wikimark import html2paragraph
from wikimark import tokenize


def process(args):
    doc2vec, regressions, filepath = args
    with filepath.open('r') as f:
        string = f.read()
    subcategories = Counter()
    for index, paragraph in enumerate(html2paragraph(string)):
        tokens = tokenize(paragraph)
        vector = doc2vec.infer_vector(tokens)
        for subcategory, model in regressions.items():
            prediction = model.predict([vector])[0]
            subcategories[subcategory] += prediction
    # compute the mean score for each subcategory
    for subcategory, prediction in subcategories.items():
        subcategories[subcategory] = prediction / (index + 1)
    # keep only the main category
    subcategory = subcategories.most_common(1)[0]
    return (filepath, subcategory)


def main():
    input = Path('./build')
    doc2vec = Doc2Vec.load(str(input / 'model.doc2vec.gz'))
    regressions = dict()
    for filepath in input.glob('./*/*/*.model'):
        with filepath.open('rb') as f:
            model = pickle.load(f)
        regressions[filepath.parent] = model

    examples = list(input.glob('../data/wikipedia/english/*'))

    with Pool() as pool:
        iterable = zip(
            [doc2vec] * len(examples),  # XXX!
            [regressions] * len(examples),  # XXX!
            examples
        )
        for filepath, subcategory in pool.imap_unordered(process, iterable):
            print('* {} -> {}'.format(filepath, subcategory))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The lines marked with `XXX!` point to the data that serialized when I call `pool.imap_unodered`. There at least 200MB of data that is serialized.

How can I avoid serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution as simple as using a global for both `doc2vec` and `regressions`.